# HOW TO Find by Object ID on MongoDB with Casbah?

Tags: scala, mongodb, casbah

I'm trying to write a query to find by Object ID with Casbah, it seems trivial but ... I don't find.

I tried this:

```
def get(id: Option[String]): User = { 
    val mongoDB : MongoDB = MongoConnection().apply("test")
    val mongoColl : MongoCollection = mongoDB.apply("users")
    val objectId = id.getOrElse().asInstanceOf[String]
    val o : DBObject = MongoDBObject("_id" -> objectId)
    val u = mongoColl.findOne(o)
    val user = new User()
    for(x <- u){
         user.id = x.getAs[String]("_id")
         user.username = x.getAs[String]("username")
         user.password = x.getAs[String]("password")
    }
    user
}
```

and this:

```
def get(id: Option[String]): User = { 
        val mongoDB : MongoDB = MongoConnection().apply("test")
        val mongoColl : MongoCollection = mongoDB.apply("users")
        val objectId = "ObjectId(\"" +id.getOrElse().asInstanceOf[String] + "\")"
        val o : DBObject = MongoDBObject("_id" -> objectId)
        val u = mongoColl.findOne(o)
        val user = new User()
        for(x <- u){
             user.id = x.getAs[String]("_id")
             user.username = x.getAs[String]("username")
             user.password = x.getAs[String]("password")
        }
        user
    }
```

This compile and run but no result.
I also tried this:

```
def get(id: Option[String]): User = { 
    val mongoDB : MongoDB = MongoConnection().apply("test")
    val mongoColl : MongoCollection = mongoDB.apply("users")
    val objectId : ObjectId = id.getOrElse().asInstanceOf[ObjectId]
    val o : DBObject = MongoDBObject("_id" -> objectId)
    val u = mongoColl.findOne(o)
    val user = new User()
    for(x <- u){
         user.id = x.getAs[String]("_id")
         user.username = x.getAs[String]("username")
         user.password = x.getAs[String]("password")
    }
    user
}
```

But this one doesn't compile because String cannot be cast to ObjectId.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.bson.types.ObjectId
```

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"_id" is typically stored as an ObjectID in MongoDB and not a String... String and ObjectID are different types and you cannot cast a String to an ObjectId.  ObjectId is a distinct type within MongoDB as well, so ObjectId("abcdefgh123") is NOT the same as the String "abcdefgh123".

You need to search by ObjectID here within Casbah.  Try this instead:

```
def get(id: Option[ObjectId]): User = { 
    val mongoDB : MongoDB = MongoConnection().apply("test")
    val mongoColl : MongoCollection = mongoDB.apply("users")
    val objectId : ObjectId = id.getOrElse().asInstanceOf[ObjectId]
    id.foreach( oid => {
      val o : DBObject = MongoDBObject("_id" -> oid)
      val u = mongoColl.findOne(o)
      val user = new User()
      for(x <- u){
        user.id = x.getAs[ObjectId]("_id")
        user.username = x.getAs[String]("username")
        user.password = x.getAs[String]("password")
      }
      user
    })
  }
```

Comment: Ok thanks @McAdams. Now it works!

`def get(id: Option[String]): User = { 
  val mongoDB : MongoDB = MongoConnection().apply("test")
  val mongoColl : MongoCollection = mongoDB.apply("users")
  val objectId : ObjectId = new ObjectId(id.getOrElse().asInstanceOf[String])
  val user = new User()  
  val o : DBObject = MongoDBObject("_id" -> objectId)
  val u = mongoColl.findOne(o)
  for(x <- u){
    user.id = x.getAs[String]("_id")
    user.fullname = x.getAs[String]("fullname")
    user.username = x.getAs[String]("username")
  }
  user
}`

Comment: You can also do mongoColl.findOne(id.get)